# How to get git file renames to NOT show as add/delete in ReviewBoard?

Tags: git, review-board

Some, I have to rename a file, and also show make a change to the file contents. I use "git mv" to rename the file in the repository. However, when I post my changes to Review Board, the ReviewBoard diff just shows as a delete/add of the whole file. I want instead the diff to show just the changes I made inside the file. Is there any way to do this?

I don't have this issue in Subversion. When I rename the file using Subversion, the ReviewBoard diff correctly shows only the changes in the actual file contents (if any).

Answer (score 0):

Try updating to the latest version.  This is claimed "generally fixed" as of Jan 2014: https://code.google.com/p/reviewboard/issues/detail?id=1235

Comment: broken link; this one works, though: https://hellosplat.com/s/beanbag/tickets/1235/